# Call values of an Ajax generated form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a problem with this

I have a table generated dinamically with ajax, and it contains a form to check the items with checkboxes, something like

```
<form name="formdocs">
```

And then

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ticado" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">
```

One for each td of the form. The problem is when i try to call the marked checkboxes with a javascript function that starts with:

```
function archive(){
    var documents = formdocs.ticado;
    var len = documents.length;
```

It fails on line 3 with: 'Cannot read property "lenght" of undefined'

Any idea?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Use an ID instead and `getElementById`

Comment: <form name="formdocs" id="documentos">
function archive(){
var documents = document.getElementById('documentos').ticado;
var len = documents.length;

Same problem... 'Cannot read property "lenght" of undefined'

Comment: You've twice said 'lenght' instead of 'length'; I'm pretty sure that isn't your problem but that's going to get folks suggesting it is.

Comment: It sounds like `ticado` does not exists when you ran `archive()` method (maybe because you call it before the table is generated with AJAX). `formdocs` should exist, otherwise you've had an error on line 2.

Comment: It exists, and i run `archive()` after the table is generated, not before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**  this function will now get you all the checkbox elements inside of your form and if you want to access their values you can just use the line from console.log()

```
function Archive(){
  var inputs = [document.getElementsByTagName("input")];
  var obj = inputs[0];
  for(var i= 0; i < obj.length; i++){
    if(obj[i].type == "checkbox"){
      console.log(obj[i].value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your method usin plain javascript doesn't works, it recognised the another inputs from the page, but not the checkboxes.

With the jquery method, i not see hoy can i use my checkboxed value asociated in each iteration.

Thanks

Comment: What does your Archive function is supposed to do ? Turn all checkboxes checked or get all the checked boxes and perform some action based on it ?

Comment: It sends the "id" of the checked checkboxes to an sql sequence that deletes the entry from the database, thats why the checkbox contains `value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">` and then i use the value with `docs[i].value`

Comment: I've updated the function, it should work now. I've tested in my localhost on a simple form. If you only want to delete the checked boxes the after the if add another one if(obj[i].checked == true) and then get the value, otherwise it will remove all the data you have